# PHP Array Increment

Tags: php, arrays, search, match

I store numbers in an array in the following way: 
467:0
where 467 is the number and 0 is the number of occurances.

What am doing is I grab a bunch of numbers from the db and then I look for numbers that appear more then once, if they do incredement the number of occurances.

```
$numberCount = explode(':', $this->_presentationArr);

    if(in_array($numberprefix  . ':' . preg_match('/^\d+$/', $numberCount[1]), $this->_presentationArr))
    {

        $pos = array_search($numberprefix  . ':' . preg_match('/^\d+$/', $numberCount[1]), $this->_presentationArr);
        $tmpArr = explode(':', $this->_presentationArr[$pos]);
        $tmpArr[1]++; # this does not work


    }
```

The $tmpArr[1] is the number that needs to be incredementet for each match. Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your question.  "Any ideas?" is quite vague.  One question though: why not just use a twodimensional array and get rid of all that parsing stuff?  Would be faster and clearer

Comment: What do expect that to do? You're not assigning or overwriting anything in the original array, that increment does nothing useful.

Comment: I know it doesnt overwrite anything but that doesnt matter since $arrPos[1] doesnt change value at all. Well it go from 0 to 1. But not to 2 and so on.

Comment: Why not simply use an array where 467 is the key and 0 is the value, or a nested array, rather than having the additional complexity of a colon-separated string

Comment: Mark: could you ellaborate your idea?

Comment: I mean you currently have an array like `$myArray = array(0 => '467:0');` which would be easier to work with if it looked like `$myArray = array(467 => 0);` which is basically what fvu has said in his answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you're overcomplicating things.  php arrays are a bit different from arrays in say C, they behave more like a map.  That means that you can just insert keys without worrying whether the previous key actually exists.  And that means that you can create your frequence map easily and quickly, like this:

```
$occurrencearray = array()
// this next line is pseudocode
while ($fetched = fetchnumber()) {
    $occurrencearray[$fetched]++;
}
// once all numbers loaded you can iterate over your occurrence map
foreach ($occurrencearray as $key => $value) {
    printf("Number %d occurs %d times",$key,$value);
    // or of course reconvert it to "key:value" strings for storing
}
```